# mysql if statement - is this possible?

Tags: mysql

I am sure mysql can do this but i dont have a clue how to write the query.

If i have the following tables:

```
Product
id    name


Product Relationship
parent_id    child_id



Product Category
id    category_name


Product Categories
product_id    category_id
```

Each product has a list of categories it is allowed to appear in and it must only be visible in those categories.

Now the difficult bit: If a parent > child product relationship exists then each child product id must also be considered as part of this rule and if any child product is not visible on a category then the whole product must not be visible.

Visibility is determined by no result in the result set returned by the query i am trying to write here.

A typical input will be product id, parent and child ids if applicable and category id.

Is this possible with a single query and if so how can i write it?

Comment: You can use the case statement. But this does look like you would need case. Just a good query should get you what you want

Comment: can you add sample data and also the desired result set

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have a number of product trees (each start at some root and descend through child nodes to the various products).  You appear to be saying that category membership is constant throughout each such tree?  That is, it can be seen as a property of the root node?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a case for an `IF` in MySQL ([which you can do](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html)), what's wrong with a subquery or a more complex `JOIN` e.g.

```
SELECT
  p.*
FROM
  `Product` p
LEFT JOIN
  `Product_Relationship` c
  ON p.id = c.parent_id OR p.id = c.child_id
WHERE
  p.id IN(
    SELECT product_id FROM `Product_Categories`
  )
  AND (
    c.id IS NULL
    OR c.id IN(
      SELECT product_id FROM `Product_Categories`
    )
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this against your schema